# Magento RESTful API for adding product to cart

Tags: php, magento, rest

Is there any RESTful API to add product to cart in Magento? I know it can be done using SOAP/XML but I am looking for solution using RESTful/JSON.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you dont want to use XML or SOAP?

Comment: Latest versions of the browsers provides native & safe support for encoding and decoding JSON.

Comment: Also, JSON is more isomorphic with the relational data stores most services use for persistence. Faster too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2015 - If you are looking for an answer like me, with Magento 2.0 this is now possible.

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html

POST /V1/carts/{cartId}/items

Look for quoteCartItemRepositoryV1. There is a post method to add product to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

right now we can just view the information using RESTful API like retrieve the inventory, orders, products, customers list and information.

Yes, you can extend the functionality of the api to add product to cart.

Comment: One year later... ;)
I've the same problem. Can you give a little hint how to start?